# Use option p of weka filter (RemoveType) in java code

Tags: java, filter, filtering, weka

I am using weka API in my java code and have a dataset with string ID to keep track of instances, weka mentioned in this [page](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Instance+ID) that there is an option `p` that can help printing the ID of each instance in the prediction result even if the attribute has removed. But how this can be approached in java code since none of the options listed in [RemoveType](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/RemoveType.html) filter is `p`?

Thank you

Comment: `-p` is an option of the classifier, not of the filter... but the page you've linked to describes using Weka from the command line, not via the Java API.

Answer (score 0):

p option, on the weka page you mentioned, is the parameter which you can set through some of the the classes which are available in the package `weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction`

With these classes you can set the things you want in output prediction file. E.g. OutputDistribution, AttributeIndices(P)- Attribute indices which you want to have in output file, Number of decimal places in prediction probabilities, etc.

You can use any of the below classes depending on the output file format you want.

1. PlainText
2. HTML
3. XML
4. CSV

Setting the parameters through code :

```
Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(data);
StringBuffer forPredictionsPrinting = new StringBuffer();
PlainText classifierOutput = new PlainText();
classifierOutput.setBuffer(forPredictionsPrinting);

Boolean outputDistribution = new Boolean(true);
classifierOutput.setOutputDistribution(true);
```

You can find detailed usage of this class at 
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.PlainText

Comment: I think the official source for that documentation is [here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable-3-8/weka/classifiers/evaluation/output/prediction/PlainText.html).